# Meaning of this Python statement with colon and for at the end of the line

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I'm trying to understand this syntax, but I'm not even able to find the correct reference since I don't know what the various semantic elements mean:

```
self._sensitive_ids = {xmr : self.parser.get_id(xmr) for xmr in self.sensitive}
```

Now this doesn't work in my python installation (V2.4). It says "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Could someone explain what is being assigned to the LHS, and the correct way to rewrite the statement for Python 2.4? What is the "for" loop looping over here when it's mentioned at the end of the line?

Btw, the original code is from here: [vcd_parse](https://github.com/GordonMcGregor/vcd_parser/blob/master/vcd/watcher.py)

Comment: Why are you on 2.4? If at all possible, you should upgrade.

Comment: @user2357112  because I'm not the one installing it on our company's systems :(  Is there a way I can install a non-admin version of python in my home directory?

Comment: You can, actually! There are a number of ways you could do that, depending on what you want to use Python for, what OS you're on, and how comfortable you are compiling things from source. You could [download Python 3.6.3](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-363/) from python.org, or get [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) or some other distribution.

Comment: Python 2.4 is an _old_ version. If the code was written for a later version (as this must have been, since it includes a dictionary comprehension), then it likely uses a lot of language features that weren't in Python 2.4. You will not find it easy to backport. The good news is, you can indeed install a non-admin Python. I'd recommend taking a look at Anaconda or Miniconda (neither requires Admin access).

Comment: @user2357112 & Matthias  Thank you. I'll look into this now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, that's a dictionary comprehension, which isn't available in Python 2 until version 2.7.

In Python 2.5 and later you can use a generator expression inside the `dict` constructor:

```
self._sensitive_ids = dict((xmr, self.parser.get_id(xmr)) for xmr in self.sensitive)
```

In Python 2.4, you can use a list comprehension inside the `dict` constructor:

```
self._sensitive_ids = dict([(xmr, self.parser.get_id(xmr)) for xmr in self.sensitive])
```

Actually, you *can* also use the generator expression version in Python 2.4. I'm a little hazy, it's a while since I used 2,4. ;)

You can read about list comprehensions in [the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: [Additional reference.](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.4.html#pep-289-generator-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

```
self._sensitive_ids = {xmr : self.parser.get_id(xmr) for xmr in self.sensitive}
```

is equivalent to:

```
self._sensitive_ids = {}
for xmr in self.sensitive:
    self._sensitive_ids[xmr] = self.parser.get_id(xmr)
```

Comment: Ok. The equivalent works in python 2.4. but there are many other errors i get later on. Guess the syntax errors are because of an older python version?

Comment: @SujayPhadke It should.

Answer (score 1):

This is one line `pythonic` way to define for loop inside list. below codes are same:

```
# normal way
sample_list = [1,2,10,12]
pythonic_list = []
for i in sample_list:
    pythonic_list.append(i*2)



# pythonic way
sample_list = [1,2,10,12]
pythonic_list = [i*2 for i in sample_list]
```

in your case :

```
self._sensitive_ids = {xmr : self.parser.get_id(xmr) for xmr in self.sensitive}
```

is same as :

```
self._sensitive_ids = {}
for xmr in self.sensitive:
    self._sensitive_ids[xmr] = self.parser.get_id(xmr)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a dictionary comprehension that maps `xmr` key to `self.parser.get_id(xmr)` values; it builds the dictionary from each `(key, value)` pairs:
`(xmr`, `self.parser.get_id(xmr))` pairs

```
self._sensitive_ids = {xmr1 : self.parser.get_id(xmr1),  # for each xmr in self.sensitive, maps the corresponding parser value
                       xmr2 : self.parser.get_id(xmr2),
                       ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.senstive` is an attribute of an object, which is a list of xmr(s).

Now code writer want to create a dictionary with keys as xmr(s) and values of id(s) of the xmr(s).

the way he is doing it is called the dictionary comprehension.

End output dictionary looks like below

```
{xmr_1 : xmr_id_1, xmr_2 : xmr_id_2,.....so on}
```